# Overriding the way Twig finds the views?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.3

I'm new to Symfony, and so far I just love it!

Right now, I'm playing around with different personal hobby projects and I've come across something I do not seem to be able to wrap my head around.

---

I'm running Symfony 3.3.6 right now. I'm trying to kind of add a `theme` functionality to my project. Right now, I've got my Bundles that got their own views, which I can overwrite inside of `app/Resources/views/`. So right now, out of the box Symfony kind of supports a base view, with overwriting possibility.

What I would like to achieve is one more level of fallback.

I would like to make twig FIRST look into a theme folder, where the `[THEME]` would be a config.

1) Look for file inside of /app/theme/[THEME]/resources/view
2) Look for file inside of /app/theme/[THEME]/resources/[BUNDLE]/view

---

I would also like this to happen from inside a bundle, for example ThemeBundle.

Basically I would like to have a Bundle, that would take of the logic for Twig on how to find the views. It's really important that all the code, right now, would still work. So I do not wish to add a a path variable or something similar, but **I would actually like to modify the behavior of TwigBundle from my own Bundle!**

Is this sort of thing possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour] and [ask]

Comment: What's wrong with my question? It would be a lot more helpful if you actually pointed out what is wrong with the question, instead of just saying 'it's wrong, read this'.

Comment: What's wrong is that you are not clear enough about what you have done to address the issues. Also some code maybe?

Comment: But I've got no code, since I'm not able to address the issue. If I would have had code, I would have pasted it. But I've got nothing. I though my question was pretty clear.

Comment: Well, do not expect someone to write it for you. You MUST show some effort. Try to explain what you think could be the procedure to solve the issue and not only what your aim is.

Answer (score 1):

Twig has a built-in feature to achieve what you want called **namespaces**.

Twig will always load the first template that exists in a namespace, starting from the first configured path.

Configure the paths in your `app/config/config.yml` like this:

```
twig:
    # ...
    paths:
        '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/acme/themes/theme1': theme
        '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/acme/themes/theme2': theme
        '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/acme/themes/common': theme
```

Then use the namespace in your template like this:

```
{{ include('@theme/header.twig') }}
```

See the documentation chapter [Multiple Paths per Namespace](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/namespaced_paths.html#multiple-paths-per-namespace).

In order to dynamically add more paths living inside bundle directories you can use a compiler pass inside the corresponding bundle to add them.